# Use a 'by' function then bind results to original data

Tags: r

I'm trying to use R to identify bad data automatically.  Historically, this has been done by taking all the data in one quarter, calculating a mean and standard deviation, then culling any value more than 4 SD away - then, on the culled data, doing the same thing again (some values are so ridiculous that there is another level of ridiculousness underneath it).  Right or wrong, this is the technique being used.  I'm trying to write R code to do this using the by function but I don't know how to bind the results of the by function to the original data.

Consider:

```
x <- c(3,3,3,4,4,4) #values of interest
g <- c('1','1','1','2','2','2') #grouping variable
gmeans <- by(x,g,mean)
```

the `gmeans` is a 'by' object which can be coerced into a matrix or a list, but is there an easy way to take those means and `cbind()` them to the original data, `x`?  I know about `merge()` but `gmeans` doesn't have a key by default to use in joining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave` instead, then put altogether in a data.frame

```
> data.frame(x, g, mean=ave(x, g, FUN=mean))
  x g mean
1 3 1    3
2 3 1    3
3 3 1    3
4 4 2    4
5 4 2    4
6 4 2    4
```

Comment: +1 Was about to post the same thing except with `cbind`. As a bonus, if the function is `mean`, it can be left out with `ave` :-)

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of ave.  This is fantastic.